# LSTM forgetting dependencies

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, lstm

How does a LSTM network know when is a good time to forget the dependencies it has learned? I understand that it forgets when the value of forget gate is close to zero. But how does it know when to let the forget gate output a value close enough to zero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a typical LSTM block forget gate computes its value based on its inputs (from layer below) and weights associated with each input. Weights are trained, usually by gradient descent using gradients that are computed by backpropagation.

You can think of forget gate as simple logistic regression classifier that is trained to classify inputs into two classes (forget/not forget). Hovewer, in LSTM case one don't expicitly assign classes to inputs because output error is backpropagated from above units.

Thus, one can (informally) say that forget gate learns optimal time to forget by adjusting weights on its inputs in a way that minimizes overall network output error.

Comment: Lets say I train an LSTM network with sequence length of 200. Once the training ended I decided to test it with a sequence longer than 200. Say I input a sequence with the length of 500. So the network will not remember as much as 500 past activations? Only 200 as it is trained?

Comment: @dnth Theoretically, LSTM can remember information for longer times since forget/write gates typically work on current input, so information can be retained until something in current input won't trigger erasure/rewrite, independent of the exact number of timesteps that passed. In practice, results may vary depending on your task and the way LSTM was trained.

Answer (score 0):

The forget gate simply applies to the stored cell value. If forget is closer to 1, he takes the stored value into account, otherwise, stored value will be ignored, he just gotta find a value for the forget value in which the error is minimized.